# Find the row that met certain criteria with latest date vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have this table below. What I am trying to achieve through Excel VBA is loop through the table below to find a person's name at the latest date and give me the units she/he purchased.

[image]

?: What is the best or simplest way to get the "Units" purchased on the latest "Meeting Date" when search by "Name"

Let us say I Choose Gerry, the result will give me "30" as it is the units purchased on the latest "Meeting Date" Sorry I am new to Excel VBA.

My challenge also is also after going through all rows that has "gerry", how can I get the row that has the latest date?

I will update the question if it needs some clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to use `VBA` or can you use sheet formulas?

Comment: I need to use vba.

Comment: The easiest way is probably sorting the table by date (descending) and units (descending).  If sorted, the first occurrence of a name will always have the most recent date for that user and also the highest number of units for that user on the date.

Comment: There are many ways to get the results you want in VBA. Please show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems. One approach would be to loop through or filter the range to look at just "Gerry"; then examine the related dates to find the Max Date.  You could use an array, dictionary or collection to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need VBA to do it you could use ADODB like that:

```
Sub ReadFromWorksheetADO(selName As String)
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
        & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"


    Dim query As String
    query = "SELECT * FROM [data$]"

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open query, conn
        .Sort = "Meeting_Date DESC"
        .Filter = "Name = '" & selName & "'"
    End With


    Debug.Print rs.Fields("Name").Value, rs.Fields("Meeting_Date").Value, rs.Fields("Units").Value
    ' Sheet2.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

And that will give you the result for *Gerry*

```
Sub TestIt()
    ReadFromWorksheetADO "Gerry"
End Sub
```

I renamend the field *Meeting Date* to **Meeting_Date**. And I assumed the sheet with the data you posted has the name **data**. You need to add a reference to the ADODB Library in the VBE ( Goto Tools/References and select Microsoft Active DataObject 6.1